# Manage Groups shows no groups after server move

Tags: groups

We moved our CiviCRM install to a new server a couple of weeks ago. Everything seemed to go smoothly, but we've now noticed that the Manage Groups page is empty:

[image]

Clues that I've got so far:

- This happens both with new users, and users that were moved over from the old server.
- I can create a new group without errors, but obviously it doesn't show up afterwards.
- Group counts show up on the contacts page tab, but no roups are shown there either.
- We followed the move process outlined at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/misc/switch-servers/.

Hopefully somebody out there's got some clues, because I'm coming up empty right now... Thanks in advance for the additional brain cells!

CiviCRM 5.11.0, Wordpress 5.2.1

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?  Delete everything under `wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c`

Answer (score 2):

Points to Aidan -- I had flushed out the caches, but hadn't cleared out the `templates_c` folder. Once I did that I discovered a permissions problem on the `templates_c/en_US` folder. With that fixed everything is working again!

Comment: Another thing I found: The CiviCRM cron job was set up in root's crontab, so when it ran various files in `templates_c` would be set to be owned by root. I moved the job into `/etc/crontab` and set it to run as the web server's account, which hopefully will keep the permissions from getting messed up again.